# Character "|" in strsplit function (vertical bar / pipe)

Tags: r

I was curious about:

```
> strsplit("ty,rr", split = ",")  
[[1]]
[1] "ty" "rr"

> strsplit("ty|rr", split = "|")
[[1]]
[1] "t" "y" "|" "r" "r"
```

Why don't I get `c("ty","rr")` from `strsplit("ty|rr", split="|")`?

Comment: Many people fail to escape this pitfall...

Comment: @joran: but it is easily fixed, true?

Comment: Thanks for posting, I had the same problem w/ ".". Per @Andrie 's link the relevant sentence is: Any metacharacter with special meaning may be quoted by preceding it with a backslash. The metacharacters in EREs are . \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ?,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because the `split` argument is interpreted as a regular expression, and `|` is a special character in a regex.

To get round this, you have two options:

Option 1: Escape the `|`, i.e. `split = "\\|"`

```
strsplit("ty|rr", split = "\\|")
[[1]]
[1] "ty" "rr"
```

Option 2: Specify `fixed = TRUE`:

```
strsplit("ty|rr", split = "|", fixed = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "ty" "rr"
```

---

Please also note the **See Also** section of `?strsplit`, which tells you to read `?"regular expression"` for details of the pattern specification.